# Flickering in VR Oculus Quest?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculusquest

There is a lot of flickering in Oculus Quest device, the flicker occurs on textures mainly, textures on models, UIs, etc. Is this due to the reason of using LWRP(Light Weight Render Pipeline)?
I have even tried to use anti aliasing and set it to 4x. But does not make any difference. Even tried the following:

```
 void Start()
      {
         OVRManager.display.displayFrequency = 72.0f;
         XRSettings.eyeTextureResolutionScale = 1.4f;         
      }
```

Comment: Flickering textures can be due to overlays, so the engine doesn't know what to render, or just wrong resolution. But generally "flickering" can mean anything, so the question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 2):

Go through this checklist,

- Make sure your game is running at **72 fps** (according to oculus docs)

***No success? (go to next step)***

- Disable **post-process** and check.

***No success? (go to next step)***

- This might be due to the **Z-fighting issue**. Multiple objects having similar Z-buffer values will start flickering. So make sure that multiple objects are not in the same position.

***Still No Success? (go to next step)***

- Try playing with **Z-buffer precision**. Try slightly **increasing the near clipping value** and slightly **decreasing the far clipping value** of the Main Camera. By doing so, the depth buffer precision increases, which might solve the flickering of textures. Do let me know if any of these procedures fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the smoothness to 0 on the material helped on my side